# Problem of loading a mobilenet model (TensorFlow and React Native)

Tags: javascript, react-native, tensorflow, mobilenet

I'm asking a question (my first question in stack overflow) about loading a mobilenet model from TensorFlow. I took a code (check this link : https://heartbeat.comet.ml/image-classification-on-react-native-with-tensorflow-js-and-mobilenet-48a39185717c) but when I launched this code in Visual Studio Code, the model didn't load. I don't know why, I set up all the dependencies.

My code in my Visual Studio file is here (adapted from this link : https://heartbeat.comet.ml/image-classification-on-react-native-with-tensorflow-js-and-mobilenet-48a39185717c)

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ActivityIndicator,
  StatusBar,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native'
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs'
import { fetch } from '@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native'
import * as mobilenet from '@tensorflow-models/mobilenet'
import * as jpeg from 'jpeg-js'
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker'
import Constants from 'expo-constants'
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions'

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isTfReady: false,
    isModelReady: false,
    predictions: null,
    image: null
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await tf.ready()
    this.setState({
      isTfReady: true
    })
    this.model = await mobilenet.load()
    this.setState({ isModelReady: true })
    this.getPermissionAsync()
  }

  getPermissionAsync = async () => {
    if (Constants.platform.ios) {
      const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL)
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!')
      }
    }
  }

  imageToTensor(rawImageData) {
    const TO_UINT8ARRAY = true
    const { width, height, data } = jpeg.decode(rawImageData, TO_UINT8ARRAY)
    // Drop the alpha channel info for mobilenet
    const buffer = new Uint8Array(width * height * 3)
    let offset = 0 // offset into original data
    for (let i = 0; i < buffer.length; i += 3) {
      buffer[i] = data[offset]
      buffer[i + 1] = data[offset + 1]
      buffer[i + 2] = data[offset + 2]

      offset += 4
    }

    return tf.tensor3d(buffer, [height, width, 3])
  }

  classifyImage = async () => {
    try {
      const imageAssetPath = Image.resolveAssetSource(this.state.image)
      const response = await fetch(imageAssetPath.uri, {}, { isBinary: true })
      const rawImageData = await response.arrayBuffer()
      const imageTensor = this.imageToTensor(rawImageData)
      const predictions = await this.model.classify(imageTensor)
      this.setState({ predictions })
      console.log(predictions)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  selectImage = async () => {
    try {
      let response = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
        allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [4, 3]
      })

      if (!response.cancelled) {
        const source = { uri: response.uri }
        this.setState({ image: source })
        this.classifyImage()
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  renderPrediction = prediction => {
    return (
      <Text key={prediction.className} style={styles.text}>
        {prediction.className}
      </Text>
    )
  }

  render() {
    const { isTfReady, isModelReady, predictions, image } = this.state

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar barStyle='light-content' />
        <View style={styles.loadingContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>
            TFJS ready? {isTfReady ? <Text>✅</Text> : ''}
          </Text>

          <View style={styles.loadingModelContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Model ready? </Text>
            {isModelReady ? (
              <Text style={styles.text}>✅</Text>
            ) : (
              <ActivityIndicator size='small' />
            )}
          </View>
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.imageWrapper}
          onPress={isModelReady ? this.selectImage : undefined}>
          {image && <Image source={image} style={styles.imageContainer} />}

          {isModelReady && !image && (
            <Text style={styles.transparentText}>Tap to choose image</Text>
          )}
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.predictionWrapper}>
          {isModelReady && image && (
            <Text style={styles.text}>
              Predictions: {predictions ? '' : 'Predicting...'}
            </Text>
          )}
          {isModelReady &&
            predictions &&
            predictions.map(p => this.renderPrediction(p))}
        </View>
        <View style={styles.footer}>
          <Text style={styles.poweredBy}>Powered by:</Text>
          <Image source={require('./assets/tfjs.jpg')} style={styles.tfLogo} />
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#171f24',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  loadingContainer: {
    marginTop: 80,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  text: {
    color: '#ffffff',
    fontSize: 16
  },
  loadingModelContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginTop: 10
  },
  imageWrapper: {
    width: 280,
    height: 280,
    padding: 10,
    borderColor: '#cf667f',
    borderWidth: 5,
    borderStyle: 'dashed',
    marginTop: 40,
    marginBottom: 10,
    position: 'relative',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  imageContainer: {
    width: 250,
    height: 250,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 10,
    left: 10,
    bottom: 10,
    right: 10
  },
  predictionWrapper: {
    height: 100,
    width: '100%',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  transparentText: {
    color: '#ffffff',
    opacity: 0.7
  },
  footer: {
    marginTop: 40
  },
  poweredBy: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: '#e69e34',
    marginBottom: 6
  },
  tfLogo: {
    width: 125,
    height: 70
  }
})

export default App
```

Comment: Welcome, new user! That is a pretty old post on the TF.js. Chances are that things have changed quite a bit in the API since then. But you might have better luck finding an answer by posting on the article itself, or looking at newer examples. Good luck!